# Passing a parameter to a class

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following class in my VB.NET application and I want to pass a new connection string on each call.

```
Public Class Dataconnect    


    Private objcon As New SqlConnection("NEW CONNECTION STRING EACH CALL")       

  Public Shared Function ExecutenonQuery(sqlcmd As SqlCommand) As Integer

        Try

            Dim objdc As New Dataconnect()         

    Dim affectedrecord As Integer = 0       

      If objdc.Opencon() = True Then

                sqlcmd.Connection = objdc.objcon           

      affectedrecord = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()           

      objdc.Closecon()              

   objdc = Nothing               

  Return affectedrecord          

   Else             

    Return affectedrecord      

       End If      

   Catch ex As Exception   

          ' new Exception("Error: In ExecuteNonquery");        

       Throw ex       

  End Try

    End Function

    Public Function Opencon() As Boolean    

     Try          

   If objcon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then    

             objcon.Open()           

  End If            

objcmd.Connection = objcon       

      Return True      

   Catch ex As Exception

            Throw New Exception("Error: In Open connesction" + ex.Message)

            Return False    

     End Try   

  End Function

    Public Function Closecon() As Boolean

        Try             If objcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

                objcon.Close()       

      End If       

      objcmd.Dispose()  

           Return True      

   Catch ex As Exception       

      Throw New Exception("Error: In Close connesction" + ex.Message)       

      Return False     

    End Try   

  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: In reference to your exception handling: Don't. http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/08/first-rule-of-exception-handling-do-not.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z08e49e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Sub New(ByVal s As String)
     objcon As New SqlConnection(s)
End Sub
```

And then:

```
Dim objdc As New Dataconnect(connectionString)
```

Learn more about classes and constructors here: http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/11/04/vbooppt2.htm

Comment: thank you for reply , please if you can update my code I will be thankful as I am not able to. thank you

Comment: Please , when I am adding following Dim objdc As New Dataconnect(connectionString)  its giving me error

Comment: That is a new question.